# exception never thrown by Exec method in java

Tags: java, process, exec, runtime.exec

I'm trying to execute system commands such as exp to backup a db. But if the login details are wrong or if the db does not exist then it does not throw an exception.

How can I handle this sort of case where exceptions are thrown?

All the helpful hands are welcomed..

Regards,
Swarupa

Answer (score 1):

Unless you can tell something from the return code of the external process, you may be out of luck.  I suppose you could maybe pipe exp's console output into a file or a stringbuffer, then parse that.  Can you back it up using JDBC instead?

Comment: Thanks Curtis for your valuable suggesstion.Right now i m trying the same.redirecting the output to  a file and serachng for thr err codre in it.But i would like to konw whether there was anyother better way to do it.With JDBC it is not possible to backup the db as exp is not a sql statement,Let me know if im wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Java exec runs an external process. You will have to get the return value of exec() which is a Process.
You should check the Process.exitValue() to see the error returned by your external process.

You can also get the inputStream from the process to see things like output of the program your are executing.

Comment: Hi Ramp,thanks for your reply.but when ever i try to get the process.exitValue() i m facing illegalthreadstateexception.If i try to get the value after reading the output of th cmd(eg dir) then i can get the correct exit value as 0 for dir and somewrongcmd 1.But i m not able to read the output of the exp cmd uisng the same prgm written for dir.here is the sample code ..

Comment: try 
{ 
Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("exp infodba/infodba@tc2007 FULL=y file=c:\\temp\\tc207_test_121.dmp"); 

//Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c gdsdfgfhg"); 


//only if we read the input ew can get the diferenr err code for failres and success
BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream())); 
String line=reader.readLine(); 
while(line!=null) 
{ 
System.out.println(line); 
line=reader.readLine(); } 

System.out.println(p.exitValue());

} 
catch(Exception e2) 
 {e2.printStackTrace();
 System.out.println("excep");}

Answer (score 0):

That depends a lot on what kind of database software you are using. I would check if the file for the database required exists. 
`if((new File("dbfilename")).exists())`

Comment: I dont think its oracle related because the problem is with exec () not with exp.Let me know if i m wrong.